# Moodle IIS Crash

Tags: iis, crash, application-pool, moodle, recycle

I have a fresh install of Moodle 2.1, PHP v5.3, Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS, MySQL, 3GB Ram, 4 CPUs.
I use Moodle as a VLE for a School, but have recently been having problems with it not responding (the browser just sits & loads, until eventually it receives a network connection error to the site).
Now, if I restart "Manage Server" in IIS - the problem is rectified, but occurs again a few days later. Some people suggested increasing the "recycling" time of the pools which kind of seemed to delay this problem, but it is starting to happen frequently again.

I have tried the Moodle forums but hit a dead end, please can anyone help? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of problems trying to get Moodle going on IIS and eventually abandoned it. It sounds a lot like you have a memory leak (in IIS, not Moodle). A temporary solution would be a scheduled task that restarts IIS before and after the school day to reset it, but this is not ideal.

The pro advice is not to use IIS at all. Apache is the industry standard, it's available as an install package for Windows and it's not enormously hard to install and configure (see [moodle.org's instructions](http://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Installing_Apache_on_Windows)). If you have come up blank on the forums and are still having trouble, then I would suggest that the small learning curve to get Apache going is probably the least work in the long run. Have a go on a test machine (could be an old desktop) and see how you get along. There are far, far more people who can help you configure Moodle on Apache than can help on IIS, which is enough reason in itself to have a go.

Sorry I can't be more helpful!